# Why does the JS parseInt function behave like this for big Integer numbers?

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have a number coming in as a string. When I try to cast it into a number it seems to be rounding it in a weird way.
`parseInt('10211688549781435')`
results in `10211688549781436`

Similarly playing around with these numbers I get the following answers:
`parseInt('10211688549781436')` results in `10211688549781436`
`parseInt('10211688549781437')` results in `10211688549781436`
`parseInt('10211688549781438')` results in `10211688549781438`
`parseInt('10211688549781439')` results in `1021168854978140`

What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: It's too big for JavaScript to handle accurately. Look into BigInt